# Firebase Storage never fully private?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have set rules for our Firebase Storage to only allow authenticated users to interact with it.

```
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /something/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I browse the details of the assets saved in the storage in the Firebase Console, I do find for each of these, a link to open these publicly (when I open the details of a file), for example:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${my-project}.appspot.com/o/${my-file}?alt=media&token=49385ae5-4df6-44ef-a313-8d1f07b59111
```

My guess is that this link is the `downloadURL` and the public access is granted through the `token`.

Therefore I understand that the storage content is actually not fully private because even if I set strong rules and even if I personally and my apps don't generate download URL, Firebase still generate automatically such url for each file and therefore, even if token are hard to find, the content is in any case accessible online publicly.

Is my understanding correct?

Or the link I found in thee Firebase console isn't the download url but a temporary link respectively the token provided by the console as an expiration life?

Or is it possible to set the Firebase Storage Bucket to not generate any download links ever?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anyone who has a downlaod URL with a valid token can access the content from anywhere.  However, if you never expose that URL to anyone, it's essentially impossible for anyone to guess that URL, even if they know the path.  The token is random and contains a tremendous amount of entropy.

If you're concerned about anyone guessing this URL with the correct token, you should also be concerned about two random atoms in the universe colliding with each other.  (That's a slight exaggeration, but you can do the math if you assume that each character of a token is a valid hex digit.)

If you're *still* paranoid, and you don't want to generate any download URL at all, you will have to manually revoke the download URL tokens, and use an upload technique that doesn't also create a download URL, and never call getDownloadUrl on any file from a client app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not a question of being paranoid or not, it's a question of data privacy. I do understand that the randomness of the token make it almost impossible to guess. That being said, that's the thing, I do NOT generate any download URL therefore it's correct, Firebase do generate automatically such urls in any case? Or there is a flag to tell Firebase to not generate it during the upload?

Comment: To answer my last question, yes Firebase do generate automatically such download url when uploading and no it does not seems that there is a way to avoid this. Therefore, I'll mark this answer as the question's answer. Yes through the token files are always public with Firebase Storage but because its complexity it makes them essentially  impossible to be discovered.

Comment: If you use one of the server SDKs to upload the file, Firebase will not attach a download token to it.  If you want to suggest to the Firebase team that client SDKs should also have such an option, feel free to file a feature request with Firebase support for that.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I'll. Thank you for your answers Doug.

Comment: Client SDKs also don't auto-generate download URLs anymore. They used to do that in the initial versions of the SDK, but the API was changed to require an explicit call in May 2018.

Comment: So no one can guess the token, but someone can still just simply pass the download link around, right?